# Very Basic std::vector iterating

Tags: c++, vector, iteration, std

```
std::vector<Ogre::SceneNode*>::iterator itr;
for(itr=mSelectedObjects.begin();itr!=mSelectedObjects.end();itr++){
    itr->showBoundingBox(true); //here
}
```

I'm getting "expression must have pointer-to-class type" on the marked line, and I'm not sure why. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace the erroneous line with:

```
(*itr)->showBoundingBox(true); //here
```

Since you're storing pointers, you need to dereference `itr` twice to get from the iterator to the object (once for the iterator and once for the pointer).

Comment: Thanks! What was the cause? (i'm assuming that it was a vector of pointers?)

Comment: @PigHead: See the updated answer. I hope this is clear enough.